# Motion Problem: Two Objects Moving Towards Each Other

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know how to do this type of question:

Starting at the same time, Cathy and David drive two cars toward each other from A and B respectively. Cathy drives 1.2 times as fast as David. When they pass by each other, they are 8 miles away from the middle point between A and B. Find the distance between A and B.

So basically this is what I have so far

D=rt so Cathy is D=1.2t and David is unknown.

Not much, so I need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d$ be the distance between $A$ and $B$ and let $s$ be David's speed. Now consider the moment in time when Cathy and David pass by each other. Observe that:

- Cathy has travelled a total distance of $0.5d + 8$.
- Cathy's speed is $1.2s$.
- David has travelled a total distance of $0.5d - 8$.

Thus, since time is distance divided by speed, we may equate Cathy and David's times to get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{0.5d + 8}{1.2s} &= \frac{0.5d - 8}{s} \\
\frac{5d + 80}{12} &= 0.5d - 8 \\
5d + 80 &= 6d - 96 \\
d &= 176
\end{align*}