# Another Two Object Moving Toward Each Other Motion Problem, but Different Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's sort of like [Motion Problem: Two Objects Moving Towards Each Other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888570/motion-problem-two-objects-moving-towards-each-other/888579#888579) but in a different form, so I'm sort of confused. It seems easier but I also don't know how to do it.

Joe and JoAnn walk toward each other from two locations 36 miles apart. If Joe departed 2 hours earlier, they would meet 2.5 hours after JoAnn departed. If JoAnn departed 2 hours earlier they would meet 3 hours after Joe departed. Find the respective speed which each walks.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense. You’re leaving something out, or stating something so sloppily that we can’t understand it. … P.S. If all you want is the respective speed, you don’t need to specify any distances. You might as well say, “Joe starts at his house and JoAnn starts at hers.”

Comment: I gave you a vote up, so please don't complain.

Comment: Thanks for the vote. Are you acknowledging that my answer is *correct*, or are you just giving me a gift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v_{Joe} (2.5+2)+v_{JoAnn} 2.5=36$

$v_{Joe} (3)+v_{JoAnn} (2+3)=36$

So we have two equations:

$v_{Joe} 4.5+v_{JoAnn} 2.5=36$

$v_{Joe} 3+v_{JoAnn} 5=36$

Now I don't think there is a problem to solve it. Try it yourself.

Comment: What is the "v" variable?

Comment: I don't understand it

Comment: $v$ is velocity

Comment: so its the speed?

Comment: Yes velocity is the speed.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the wording is a little ambiguous.  Assuming that the question means,

> If Joe depart**s** 2 hours **before JoAnn does**,
>   they will meet 2.5 hours after JoAnn depart**s**.

So the distance Joe can walk in 4.5 hours + the distance JoAnn can walk in 2.5 hours
= 36 miles.

> If JoAnn depart**s** 2 hours **before Joe does**,
>   they will meet 3 hours after Joe ***departs***.

So the distance Joe can walk in 3 hours + the distance JoAnn can walk in 5 hours
= 36 miles.

Two linear equations in two variables.

Comment: Did you understand what you said? It does not make any sense for this problem becasue there is no info what is happening for $5:00$.

Comment: ...yes.  Why would i not understand?

Comment: Because the problem makes sense in the way Scott redefined this. I understood it in the exactly same way.